# Swift: execution was interrupted reason exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift

When I use function ShakerSort(), I get a error: execution was interrupted reason exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0).

```
func ShakerSort(data : [Int]) -> [Int]
{
    var output = [Int]()
    var start=0, end=data.count-1, index : Int

    for index in start...end{output+=[data[index]];}

    while (start<=end)
    {
        for index in end...start{
            if (output[index-1]>output[index]) {var Number = output[index-1]; output[index-1]=output[index]; output[index]=Number;}
            start+=1;
            for index in start...end{
                if (output[index-1]>output[index]) {var Number = output[index-1]; output[index-1]=output[index]; output[index]=Number;}
                end-=1;
            }
        }
    }
    return output
}
let mather = [34,32,12,7,5,353,76,3]
ShakerSort(mather)
```

Comment: It's pretty clear that `index` is out of bounds. Try printing index out, or stepping through it. By the way, your declaration of `index` on line 3 is spurious - each of the `for` loops redeclares index. Also `Number` should be `let`, rather than `var`, and please don't use uppercase for variables.

Comment: Also you shouldn't use `0...data.count-1` to iterate over `data`'s indices, as it will crash for an empty array – use `0..<data.count` instead. Furthermore, `for index in end...start` looks completely wrong – you cannot form a range where the start is greater than the end.

Comment: `for index in start...end {end -= 1}` - this is extremely low quality code in *any* language